# How to plot the markers which are stored in an ArrayList by a button click?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-maps, arraylist

The markers are put on the map by the user and they get stored in an ArrayList that is stored using SQLite. The markers are shown below.
[image]

When the user clicks on View, the data is recovered as below.
[image]

When the user clicks on Update Button the all the markers on the View should get plotted on the Map. How and what code should i use to plot the values that are in the ArrayList (LatLongposition)?
How do i plot the ArrayList (LatLongposition) on Map Marker?

```
private void UpdatData() {
    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //LatLongPosition is a object of the ArrayList
            boolean isUpdate = myDb.updateData(id.getText().toString(), LatLongPosition);
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().addAll(LatLongPosition);
            Polyline p = GoogleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
            p.setPoints(LatLongPosition);
            /*if (marker1 == null) {
                marker1 = GoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(p)
                                .title("Start Position")
                                .snippet(String.valueOf(googleMap.getCameraPosition()))
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                );*/
            if (isUpdate == true)
                Toast.makeText(ActivityMapDisplay.this, "Data Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(ActivityMapDisplay.this, "Data Not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate over your `List`:

```
for (LatLng position : LatLongPosition) {
    GoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
}
```

Anyway, take into account that you must follow code conventions, and variable names must begin with a lowercase character. Thus your `GoogleMap` must be named `googleMap` and your `LatLongPosition` variable must be named `latLongPosition`.

Comment: Should i write some code on the DatabaseHelper class ? for the Update Method ? because i did put the above code but the markers are not getting plotted.

Comment: What is the name of your ArrayList of LatLng? Is your ArrayList empty on your onClick method?

Comment: its - private final ArrayList<LatLng> LatLongPosition = new ArrayList<>();  , The ArrayList is not empty when its on onClick method

Comment: And is it entering the for loop?

Comment: Yes, i checked with a toast.instead of a Log.